# how to change the class of an element in javascript when an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navbar

i am trying to make a navigation bar for a webpage with sliding jquery panels. i want a small triangle under the button to appear when it is clicked and the arrow under the button corresponding with the previous page disapperas.

my HTML is:

```
<div id="navbar">
    <div id="navbar_div">
        <div class="navbar_container">
            <ul id="nav" class="sf-menu">
                <li class="bttn1 clicked" class="bttn1"><a href="#item1" class="panel" onclick="bttn1click ()">Home<span class="subheading">Welcome to our page!</span></a></li>
                <li class="bttn2 notclicked"><a href="#item2" class="panel" onclick="bttn2click ()">About Us<span class="subheading">About the website and what it does</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my css is:

```
#nav > li.clicked {
    background: url(../images/menu-arrow.png) no-repeat center bottom;
}
```

my script is in the head of the page for button 2 click is:

```
function bttn2click () {
    $("li.clicked").removeclass("clicked");
    $("li.bttn2").addclass('clicked');
    $("li.bttn2").removeclass("notclicked");
}
```

i don't know what i am meant to do. when i click buttons nothing happens (except for the links) i am aiming to change the class to match the clicked css class but it doesn't seem to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a jQuery event handler

```
<li class="bttn1 clicked" class="bttn1"><a href="#item1" class="panel">Home<span class="subheading">Welcome to our page!</span></a></li>
```

then

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('#nav li').click(function () {
        $("#nav li.clicked").removeClass("clicked");
        $(this).addClass('clicked').removeClass("notclicked");
    })
})
```

Why yours is not working because the `bttn2click` is unaware about which `li` is clicked(along with the issues with method name)

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pbJUc/)

Answer (score 1):

[`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass) and [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass) are case sensitive. jQuery does not have `addclass` or `removeclass` functions.